# stuck in this inequality

Tags: inequality

$n\in N_+,n\geq 2,x_i>-1,\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=n$ prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+x_i}\geq\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{1+x_i^2}.$$

Comment: You have to provide the context of the question and your work so far to get good answers appropriate to your context. As you seem be new here, see how others ask questions, especially the well rated ones...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$f(x)=\frac1{1+x}-\frac{x}{1+x^2}+\frac{x-1}4\geqslant0$$

For more, show your work in the question above.